# .htaccess rule for removing www from url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Whenever someone hits

```
http://www.example/consumer-complaints
```

it should become

```
http://example.com/consumer-complaints
```

The copy&paste .htaccess rules do not seem to work for me. 
It removes www when someone hits

```
> http://www.example/consumer-complaints
```

but it redirects to only http://example.com

instead of

http://example.com/consumer-complaints

Can someone write an .htaccess rule for me

Thank you

Comment: Show us your current htaccess and what you have tried, and we can take it from there

Answer (score 0):

The .htaccess Code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Conversely, if you'd prefer to use "www" in all of your URLs, you can code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: how are you including this in your .htaccess file?